# Add items in nested dictionaries based on ID number in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested

I have dictionaries nested in a list. The dictionaries are set up as follows:

`{'ID': 123, 'Balance': 45, 'Comments': None}`

I have multiple of these dictionaries in a list, so the list looks like this:

```
[{'ID': 123, 'Balance': 45, 'Comments': None}, {'ID': 456, 'Balance': 78, 'Comments': None}]
```

What I'm trying to do, is check to see if there is already a dictionary with the ID from the input in the list, and if there is, add the Balance from the input. 
Is there any readable pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

What I'm hearing here is "how do I get an item from a list, given that I know some unique key value about it?". How much are you committed to keeping the current data structure? I'm inclined to dispense with the list entirely and use a dict-of-dicts.

```
d = {
    123: {'Balance': 45, 'Comments': None}
    456: {'Balance': 78, 'Comments': None}
}
```

now checking if an id exists is just `if some_id in d:` and adding to the balance is `d[some_id]["Balance"] += some_amount`.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [{'ID': 123, 'Balance': 45, 'Comments': None}, {'ID': 456, 'Balance': 78, 'Comments': None}]
any( inputData == item['ID'] for item in data )

inputData = 123
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the list, check that whether there is match with the `ID`, if yes, add the value to the existing value of `BALANCE` of that dict. Below is the sample code:

```
>>> my_dict_list = [{'ID': 123, 'Balance': 45, 'Comments': None}, {'ID': 456, 'Balance': 78, 'Comments': None}]
>>> 
>>> new_id = int(raw_input())
123
>>> for dict_obj in my_dict_list:
...     if new_id == dict_obj['ID']:
...         dict_obj['Balance'] += float(raw_input())
... 
34
>>> my_dict_list
[{'Balance': 79.0, 'ID': 123, 'Comments': None}, {'Balance': 78, 'ID': 456, 'Comments': None}]
# Value updated for "ID" 123
```

Answer (score 0):

```
accounts = [
    {'ID': 123, 'Balance': 45, 'Comments': None}, 
    {'ID': 456, 'Balance': 78, 'Comments': None},
]

def update_balance(account_id, amount):
    account = next((a for a in accounts if a['ID'] == account_id), None)
    if account:
        account['Balance'] += amount
        return account

account = int(input('Account ID: '))
amount = float(input('Amount: '))

update_balance(account, amount)
```